# Wants to play piano but hands hurt

Tags: piano

Is it possible to relax your hands (wrists) for playing piano at 26yo or is it too late?

I am a male, a programmer by trade, so my wrists are already a problem. I used to do gymnastics for many years so my hands a little bit clamped. It saves only that I played the guitar a little, so the right hand is more flexible, but it surprisingly hurts the most from playing.

Can I do something with this? Want to play a lot but my hands hurt :(

Comment: Victor Borge was still playing at 90, so there's time yet. If you have, or suspect, a medical condition, see a doctor. We are not doctors.

Comment: My sympathies for your hand pain... it is surely deal-with-able at your young age, but you should see a doc and physical therapist about a "come-back" from your current state.

Comment: It’s not too late at all. I’m almost 49 and have made significant progress in this area. One thing to start with is plenty of sleep, good diet, and cardio 3+ times a week. It’s helped me a lot to give up caffeine and cut way back on sugar also.

Comment: The same as with with any physical activity, it helps to start with short sessions and gradually work on your endurance. For what other activities do, I found that practicing karate improved my piano playing too.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it needs to be addressed with a doctor. After a diagnosis is made, the question could be updated to ask for practice techniques in line with the doctor's recommendation.

Comment: Very few (possibly none) of the contributers here will be qualified to answer the question.  Advice given by unqualified people is potentially not good and could even be harmful.

Answer (score 0):

Almost every change in behavior especially physical movements, repetition, weight, strengthening, rotation is going together with some pain or hurt. Just start slightly and don't practice excessively and take a rest if you get an inflamation - or better before!